# How can hide bars that does not have values in matplotlib bar plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a code that plots the total transactions per months. The dataset doesn't include all the months (Only from 10 to 4). Yet when I plot it, it still includes the months from 5 to 9 (with, of course, no bars). I want to hide those as they are not even part of the dataset.

here is what I get:

[image]

here is my code

```
df_month = df.groupby('Month')['Transaction'].count()
months_unique = df.Month.unique()
df_month = df_month.reindex(months_unique, axis=0) # This line and the line above are to reorder the months as they are in the original dataframe (the first line orders them starting from 1. wrong)

df_month = df_month.to_frame()
df_month.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True) #resetting the index istead of having the month as an index. 

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10)) # specify the size of the plot

plt.bar(months_unique, df_month['Transaction'])
plt.suptitle('Transactions over the months', fontsize=25) # Specify the suptitle of the plot
plt.title('Using Data from Years October - April', fontsize=20) # Specify the title of the plot
plt.xlabel('month', fontsize=20) # Specify the x label
plt.ylabel('number', fontsize=20) # Specify the y label

plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(),fontsize=20)
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_yticklabels(), fontsize=20)
```

EDIT

How does the result of `df_month = df.groupby('Month')['Transaction'].count()` look like ?:

[image]

After using `to_frame` and `reset_index`:

[image]

Comment: Try converting `months_unique`to category `months_unique = df.Month.unique().astype('category')`

Comment: @fmarm didn't work. it says 'data type "category" not understood'

Comment: Can you please show how your `df_month` looks like after performing `df.groupby('Month')['Transaction'].count()`?

Comment: @RedowanDelowar post edited.

Comment: Why don't you just let `pandas` handle that for you? `df.groupby('Month')['Transaction'].count().plot(kind="bar"); plt.show()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way might be casting your `month` to `str` to avoid `matplotlib` filling up the missing numbers:

```
plt.bar(months_unique.astype(str), df_month['Transaction'])
...
```

Or simply let `pandas` handle the plotting for you instead:

```
df.groupby('Month')['Transaction'].count().plot(kind="bar")
...
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line before the plotting code.

```
df_month_for_plot = df_month[df_month['Transaction']!=0]
```

Then plot `df_month_for_plot` instead of `df_month`.

Comment: It gives the exact same dataframe. because there's no month (in the dataframe) where transactions are 0 in the first place.